# Will Umbraco work with a huge website?

Tags: c#, mysql, umbraco

I am planning on using [umbraco](http://umbraco.com/) to run a huge content driven website. I will be using MySql since I will not be able to afford SQL Server in the beginning. I The site will mirror other huge sites like wikipedia and answers.com. It will have millions of articles and the data may reach PetaBytes. i will host all data in one website so there will only be one installation of umbraco. I also will be expecting a number of visits per day. Do you think umbraco can handle data to these limits.

Comment: The size of the content isn't much of an issue. It's how much traffic you will be getting. I think it's a bit ambitious to be thinking 'like wikipedia' at this point. By the time you get that kind of traffic, it'll be a good problem and you can re-architect then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You would be better off asking this on the Umbraco Online Forum**

- http://our.umbraco.org/forum

**From my experience using Umbraco for corporate websites**

The chances of having petabytes of data straight off the bat are slim.  Umbraco can work with a decent amount of traffic and a modest amount of data without having to do too much to your application.  And it does supports load balancing.

You can modify the CMS using their API to optimize the site for your requirements.  And they have implemented Linq-To-Sql, and a colleague of mine has modified his version to use Fluent NHibernate and includes fetching strategies.  Which would be one of the options that you would need to do to optimize umbraco for datasets this large.

You will **need** to purchase the Courier 2 deployment package, if you are going to use a serious development, staging and production environments, and have a plan in place to know how you are going to version your XSLT templates.

**My serious recommendation**:

Do not use umbraco for a site this large until you've had a few years of experience in using Umbraco and know the API and framework inside and out.

By that time you will have a better idea of your requirements and will know if Umbraco is the right solution for you.  If it's not, then you will have better idea of the architecture you will need to implement.

Comment: what's with that self destructive edit?

Comment: rollbacked. You would have a lot of downvotes + this would be flagged as not an answer

Comment: Downvoters: Please provide a comment as to WHY you downvote this accepted answer.  As it's closed, I cannot remove it, or edit it.